# How to split concatenated strings of this kind: "howdoIsplitthis?"

Tags: string, algorithm, tokenize, text-segmentation

Suppose I have a string such as this:

```
"IgotthistextfromapdfIscraped.HowdoIsplitthis?"
```

And I want to produce:

```
"I got this text from a pdf I scraped. How do I split this?"
```

How can I do it?

Comment: "wheeloffortune" -> "wheel" "off" "or" "tune"?

Comment: @RobertLozyniak the [`python-wordsegment`](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment)'s `segment` function splits it into `['wheel', 'of', 'fortune']`. Nice isn't?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It turns out that this task is called [*word segmentation*](https://jeremykun.com/2012/01/15/word-segmentation/), and there is a [python library](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment/) that can do that:

```
>>> from wordsegment import load, segment
>>> load()
>>> segment("IgotthistextfromapdfIscraped.HowdoIsplitthis?")
['i', 'got', 'this', 'text', 'from', 'a', 'pdf', 'i', 'scraped', 'how',
 'do', 'i', 'split', 'this']
```

Answer (score 2):

Short answer: no realistic chance.

Long answer:

The only hint where to split the string is finding valid words in the string. So you need a dictionary of the expected language, containing not only the root words, but also all flexions (is that the correct linguistic term?). And then you can try to find a sequence of these words that matches the characters of your string.

Comment: ... and maybe pass it through a grammar-checker with "auto-fix"

Comment: The [python-wordsegment](https://github.com/grantjenks/python-wordsegment/) library can do what I needed in this case.